# How to web scrape JS String?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I want to do is display the "Server is up! | x Players Online!" at https://www.growtopiagame.com/ in my NodeJS app however I can't seem to find a way. I've tried cheerio and jsdom so far.

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://www.growtopiagame.com/', 
function(err, resp, html) {
        
if (!err){
          const $ = cheerio.load(html);
          console.log(html);
        
      }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've attempted?

Comment: @TomO. Hey, I've edited my post but since .server-status is writting via javascript this div is stays empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [pupeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). This will allow you to scrape web pages that contain dynamically generated elements. Won't explain how you do that exactly because the examples on the github page explain that very well.

Answer (score 1):

Im not good at JS so i cant give you a code example but you could call this URL - 'https://www.growtopiagame.com/detail'. Parse it to json and then get 'online_user'.